# How to find a import module dependency for a given variable in a source code in python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

I am trying to identify the import module name which is dependent by a variable in the script.

ex:

```py
import module1

import module2

x = module1.func()
    
y = x.func()
```

given `y`, my output should be `y` -> `x` -> `module1` and the respective line num.

Can someone help me figure this out? Just now started exploring this with AST.

Comment: All the AST module does is parse. To figure out code dependencies, you need to do control flow analysis, which is far outside of the scope of parsing. I don't think the Python library comes with a tool which does that.

Comment: @rici thanks for your reply, is there any way to group the ast.names by expression, so that i can identify they belong in one expression. ex : y= x+z; randomfunction(y). the output should group, y,x and z to group 1.randomfunction and y to group 2.

Answer (score 2):

Just using `ast` is not going to be helpful in a lot of situations. You
need to include some kind of (simulated) execution, akin of `exec()`.

For example, what can the `ast` tell from this Python program, which outputs
a string of digits? The identifier "digits" seems to come out of thin air
in the syntax tree.

```
exec('from string import digits')
mystr = digits
print(mystr)
```

And, to support the argument of execution needed, the following program
would have to result in output `nums -> int`, but just using a syntax tree, it
would probably output `nums -> string | int`.

```
import string
nums = string.digits
if True:
    nums = 0
print(nums)
```

Now, what you are asking can still be done, but rather than solve it with
abstract syntax trees, you would have more success using `trace` as a
starting point, and enhance the data collected in the various tracing calls.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I wanted to do this analysis for more than 1k scripts which I cant execute it. is this trace is a package or do you mean to trace all the variables and calls?

Comment: It's a standard library package. Looking at it's source code, you might be able to use that as a starting point for your work. BTW, I've used `ast` for listing "where used" of libraries. But that's the easy part. Evaluating true library dependency for each variable is much harder.

Comment: Ohh okay. thanks for your reply, will try it :)

Answer (score 0):

use `__name__` attribute

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy
>>> y = x.__name__
>>> y
'numpy'
```

Edit:

```
import numpy

arr = []

def a(strofwanted, library, varname):
    global arr
    arr.append([varname, library])
    return exec(strofwanted)

x = a("numpy.array([1, 2])", "numpy", "x")
>>>x
[1,2]
>>>arr
[["x", "numpy"]]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I am not trying to assign a import module and checking it. I am trying to find the variables which uses the import module. ___

Comment: No, 
import ast
tree = ast.parse(code)
x=tree.value[0]

if x is given my ouput should be ast

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be that your dependencies change dynamically.
They are simply static dependencies and keeping tap on every variable running around would be more heftier that your script/program load.

If you want to include only static dependencies you can do it using my tool:

https://github.com/bedbad/pyimports

In particular you work around ast like this:

```
def get_imports(path):
    imports = dict()
    with open(path) as fh:
        root = ast.parse(fh.read(), path)
        for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(root):
            if isinstance(node, ast.Import):
                temp = imports
                for n in node.names:
                    namelist = n.name.split('.')
                    if len(namelist) > 1:
                        for st in namelist:
                            temp[st] = dict()
                            temp = temp[st]
                    else:
                        temp[n.name] = dict()
            elif isinstance(node, ast.ImportFrom):
                temp = imports
                namelist = node.module.split('.')
                for n in namelist:
                    temp[n] = dict()
                    temp = temp[n]
                for n in node.names:
                    temp[n.name] = dict()
            else:
                continue
 return imports
```